# apk not install on Bluestack3

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0, bluestacks

I got an error when Launching app

$ adb install-multiple -r -t E:\workspace\WorkManagementDemo\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\dep\dependencies.apk E:\workspace\WorkManagementDemo\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_0.apk E:\workspace\WorkManagementDemo\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_2.apk E:\workspace\WorkManagementDemo\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_3.apk E:\workspace\WorkManagementDemo\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_4.apk E:\workspace\WorkManagementDemo\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_1.apk E:\workspace\WorkManagementDemo\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_5.apk E:\workspace\WorkManagementDemo\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_6.apk E:\workspace\WorkManagementDemo\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_8.apk E:\workspace\WorkManagementDemo\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_9.apk E:\workspace\WorkManagementDemo\app\build\intermediates\instant-run-apk\debug\app-debug.apk E:\workspace\WorkManagementDemo\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_7.apk

> $ adb shell pm uninstall com.example.workmanagementdemo
>   `Error while Installing APKs`

Answer (score 0):

try to generate combined apk for screen density and CPU architecture

```
android {
.....

    splits {
        density {
            enable true
            reset()
            include "mdpi", "xhdpi"
        }
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include "mips64", "mips"
        }
    }
}
```